# C# Updating Data Issue

Tags: c#

I am currently using one button for inserting/updating content within a table. It then takes the uploaded CSV and inserts or updates it into a data table depending on whether the row exists or not.

Here is the code fired after the button's OnClick:

```
if (ExcelDDL.SelectedValue == "Time Points" && fileName == "TimePoints.csv")
            {
                var GetTPoints = (SEPTA_DS.TimePointsTBLDataTable)tpta.GetDataByCategory(CategoryDDL.SelectedItem.ToString());

                //Loop through each row and insert into database
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in TempRouteDataTable.Rows)
                {
                    //Gather column headers
                    var category = Convert.ToString(CategoryDDL.SelectedItem);
                    var agency = Convert.ToString(row["Agency"]);
                    if (agency == null || agency == "")
                    {
                        //If row is empty skip it entirely
                        goto skipped;
                    }
                    var route = Convert.ToString(row["Route"]);
                    var GetRShortName = (SEPTA_DS.RoutesTBLDataTable)rta.GetDataByRouteID(route);
                    var newRoute = "";
                    if (GetRShortName.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        newRoute = Convert.ToString(GetRShortName.Rows[0]["route_short_name"]);
                    }

                    var direction = Convert.ToString(row["Direction"]);
                    var serviceKey = Convert.ToString(row["Service Key"]);
                    var language = Convert.ToString(row["Language"]);
                    var stopID = Convert.ToString(row["Stop ID"]);
                    var stopName = Convert.ToString(row["Stop Name"]);

                    if (stopName.Contains("accessible"))
                    {
                        string[] noHTML = stopName.Split('>');
                        int insertH = Convert.ToInt32(hta.InsertHandicapRow(newRoute,noHTML[2]));
                    }
                    var sequence = Convert.ToString(row["Sequence"]);
                    var origID = -1;

                    if (GetTPoints.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        origID = Convert.ToInt32(GetTPoints.Rows[i]["TPointsID"]);
                        var GetID = (SEPTA_DS.TimePointsTBLDataTable)tpta.GetDataByID(origID);
                        if (GetID.Rows.Count < 1)
                        {
                            origID = -1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (origID == -1)
                    {
                        int insertData = Convert.ToInt32(tpta.InsertTimePoints(category, agency, newRoute, direction, serviceKey, language, stopID, stopName, sequence));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int updateData = Convert.ToInt32(tpta.UpdateTimePoints(category, agency, newRoute, direction, serviceKey, language, stopID, stopName, sequence, origID));
                    }
                    skipped:
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

You can see how I check whether to insert or update around the bottom. I am using this method across other sections of this program and it works just fine. But in this case it is distorting my datatable immensely and I can't figure out why.

This is the bottom part of my table after inserting [no items currently within the database]:

[image]

This is the table after reuploading the CSV with data already existing within the table:

[image]

I am also getting this error when updating `There is no row at position 2230.`
What is going wrong in the code to cause this huge shift? I am just checking to see if the ID exists and if it does update rather than insert.

Also the reason i am using `goto` is because there are blank rows in the document that need to be skipped.

Comment: On the `goto`: it can be easily removed if you want. Just make a regular `for` cycle, as it should be (there are clear initialization and increment phases, and I guess `Rows` is indexable) and use the `continue` keyword to skip an iteration.

Comment: it would also be a good thing (tm) to change this: agency == null || agency == "" to this: string.IsNullOrEmpty( agency ) if your .net 4, you can use string.IsNullOrWhitespace()

Comment: @Maud'Dib Thanks that is a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your TPointsID column, a auto-generated number? If so, since you are skipping the empty row, some referential integrity problem might be occuring,because of empty data in the skipped rows in the database.

---

From the error : *There is no row at position 2230* , it is also understood that, because of the skipping you might be trying to access some non existent row in the datatable.

Also, if possible consider using the ADO.NET DataAdapter which has got the CRUD operation capability. You can find more about it at : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308507

Comment: I am skipping a row in the uploaded file, not in the database. Does that nullify your first response?

Comment: perhaps that could. Better try to build a bit more reliable logic using for/foreach loop and try to remove the goto: statement. Then atleast you can know exactly what is happening. If it still doen't solve your problem, try putting a try..catch around the above code snippet and examine the Inner Exception / Stack trace.

Comment: the `goto` is only skipping if the uploaded file has a blank row and it's still iterating.

Comment: I feel, your foreach(...) iteration index and the counter index : i are asynchronous. Can you just check it once? Also it will be better to replace foreach(...) with, for(...) and continue statement in conjunction.  If this is all going fine then there could be a problem with your data somewhere, since you told it was working fine in other parts of the application.

Comment: Yeah the `goto` statement was definitely the culprit.

Comment: Yeha I am unsure why it would be causing it. All it's doing is skipping code. Oh well. Thanks for your help. I will! I would change your answer slightly to say that it was the `goto`